Solidity selfdestruct() Deprecated - What Are the Alternatives?
I've been meaning to ask about alternatives to selfdestruct() in recent Solidity versions (^0.8.xx).
Since the deprecation of selfdestruct(), what alternative methods can be used to remove the bytecode from the blockchain?
My Findings:
The selfdestruct method will still work as before if it is called in the same transaction that creates the contract.
Confusion:
Won't this cause the contract to be destroyed immediately upon deployment, which is usually not the desired behavior? For instance, if we call selfdestruct in the constructor, the contract would look like this:
// Constructor
constructor() {
    // If you want to call selfdestruct in the constructor (which is not typically useful)
    selfdestruct(payable(MY_ADDRESS));
}

The selfdestruct method still sends the remaining Ether to the target address but no longer removes the bytecode and state data from the blockchain as of the Cancun hard fork (EIP-6780).
What are the best practices or alternative approaches for killing a contract's functionality without using selfdestruct? How can we ensure that a contract becomes inactive while adhering to the new standards?
Thank you for your insights!

There's no exact alternative to remove the bytecode, but the behaviour of the contract can still be updated using the proxy upgradable architecture.
selfdestruct was intentionally removed because it was breaking the principle of immutability i.e., an important guarantee for users on blockchain.
You can read more about this in this article as well as in Vitalik Buterin's article.
So, the best practice for changing the functionality and behavior of a contract is to use the Proxy Upgrade Pattern.

Very insightful article

Another method to kill a contract's functionality can be using the circuit breaker method or the pause-unpause methodology for all the functions.
If the contract is paused, all functions cease to exist.
Edit 1:
// Function to update the value (can be paused)
    function updateValue(uint256 newValue) public whenNotPaused {
        value = newValue;
        emit ValueUpdated(newValue);
    }
// Function to get the current value (not affected by pause)
function getValue() public view returns (uint256) {
    return value;
}

// Function to pause the contract
function pauseContract() public onlyOwner {
    _pause();
}`

The above 3 functions can be an example. Whenever you want some functionality to be stopped, you can call the pause function.

What is the circuit breaker method? Can you please demonstrate with code?

Edited the answer. Let me know if it is clear enough.

Okay, did some research on circuit breaker and pause functionality. Very insigthful

Glad you found it insightful. Feel free to upvote the answer so, that it can help others too.
